# Squelch Function - microphone preamplier

Tags: operational-amplifier, microphone

I would like to add a squelch function to this mic preamp:
[image]

EDIT: NE5534 pinout per SPICE model

[image]

Output should only be present when minimum input signal amplitude is reached. If I leave it as it is, there's some background noise due to mandatory use of a sensitive microphone.

I tried Google but solutions seem to be only for RF applications.

As a starting point, I would like output to be ON once input amplitude is at least 50mV.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The 5534 pinout has several errors.  Pins 2 and 4 appear to be correct, but the rest are wrong, and pin 8 is missing.  It would help if you used the more conventional opamp symbol.

Comment: pinout details added, thanks. prototype done and broadband noise is present.

Comment: Squelch ircuits are used in radio recievers to close the audio channel when the background noise is too high. It measures noise not signal. A voice activated chaannel is used at the audio source or the input to a PA.. It measures the amount of signal an opens the audio channel when it is strong enough. Generally the background noise coming from the mcrophone preamp is small, so a squelch circuit is likely ineffective. **Which are you trying to implement?** You need to understand the terminilogy. Then tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi RussellH, essentially, 'hiss' or broadband or white noise can be heard on the output (eg LINE IN of Behringer ADA8200 then earphone or speaker at LINE OUT of ADA8200).

Comment: Pinout still is incorrect.  See page 3:  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5534.pdf

Answer (score 4):

What you are probably looking for is referred to as a *noise gate*. Searching for that will probably get you better results.

Another option may be a noise cancelling setup. For this a second microphone is used to pick up the background noise which is then subtracted from the main microphone’s signal. A small electret mic pointed away from the desired sound source and then mixed 180 degrees out of phase should work. I have also seen microphones with the diaphragm open on both sides and a small hole in the back of the microphone allows ambient noise to reach the back of the diaphragm, cancelling noise, but this is a specially made microphone element so not an option in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The 5534 pinout still is incorrect.  See page 3 of this datasheet:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5534.pdf

Here are an assortment of noise gate circuit schematics.

https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrFYHFfU7dkGwET6z5XNyoA;_ylu=Y29sbwNiZjEEcG9zAzEEdnRpZANDQVEyNTUyM0FfMQRzZWMDc2M-?p=noise+gate+schematic&fr=fp-top